# Microsoft SQL 2016 decode Base64 column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I need help in decoding a Base64 password column in my database.  When I copy a single column content into https://www.base64decode.org/ it decodes perfectly.  I just need to perform this on ~7000 rows in this column.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found this code that works when I paste in any value from the column.  Now I just need to know how to use this to take from the password column and put into a new table as a decoded result. Thank you.

Comment: please explain with some data and explain expected result.your question is not clear

Comment: Have you attempted to do anything to solve your issue?

Comment: Are you trying to decode from SQL Server Management Studio, or through your own application, or what? More information would help you get an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following ([source](http://blog.falafel.com/t-sql-easy-base64-encoding-and-decoding/)):

```
declare @source varbinary(max), @encoded varchar(max), @decoded varbinary(max)

set @source = convert(varbinary(max), 'Hello Base64')

set @encoded = cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@source"))', 'varchar(max)') set @decoded = cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@encoded"))', 'varbinary(max)')

select convert(varchar(max), @source) as source_varchar, @source as source_binary, @encoded as encoded, @decoded as decoded_binary, convert(varchar(max), @decoded) as decoded_varchar
```

... but, creating a function for this, then:

```
create function fnDecodeBase64 (@encoded as varchar(max))
returns varchar(max)
as
begin

    declare @decoded varchar(max)

    set @decoded = cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@encoded"))', 'varbinary(max)')

    return @decoded

end
```

So, you can use:

```
select dbo.fnDecodeBase64(some_column) from Some_Table
```

You can also use:

```
select convert(varchar(max),cast(N'' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("t.SomeColumn"))', 'varbinary(max)')) as converted_64_column
from SomeTable as t
```

The keywords: `sql:column` makes the difference

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do this within Management Studio (or T-SQL directly), then you can accomplish it like this:

```
declare @source varbinary(max), @encoded varchar(max), @decoded varbinary(max)

set @source = convert(varbinary(max), 'Hello Base64')

set @encoded = cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@source"))', 'varchar(max)')
set @decoded = cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@encoded"))', 'varbinary(max)')

select convert(varchar(max), @source) as source_varchar, @source as source_binary, @encoded as encoded, @decoded as decoded_binary, convert(varchar(max), @decoded) as decoded_varchar
```

Reference: [T-SQL: Easy Base64 Encoding and Decoding](http://web.archive.org/web/20160416150016/http://blog.falafel.com/t-sql-easy-base64-encoding-and-decoding/)