# How to update a varbinary column with base64 string to bytes?

Tags: sql-server

I want to update a `varbinary` column with base64 string (an image) to bytes in SQL Server.

Does anyone know how to do it?

I need to have the image in bytes.

Thanks!

Comment: `varbinary` is for storing **binary** data - if you convert an image through base64 encoding, it now is a **string** and should be stored as such - in a `varchar(max)` column (**not** in `varbinary`).

Comment: Apparently you used some tool to do the encoding. Likewise, that same tool should be able to convert back to actual binary blob. Alternatives can be found by [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+base64+site:stackoverflow.com&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS727US727&sxsrf=ALeKk00KyAxMXBv5c_kH_CDDzccSbkZnqw:1619814642990&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwistJbj56bwAhVukuAKHX4ODs0QrQIoBHoECAcQBQ&biw=1920&bih=937).

Comment: In my case, I had a physical file but no way through SSMS (that I could find) to "upload" that file into the database. There are numerous ways to get the base64 string of an image but that doesn't convert it to the hex format needed in a query to update the value. The `xs:base64Binary` answer below solved it and wouldn't have been found without this question.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the XML Query function `xs:base64Binary()` to encode and decode Base64 data for you:

- When given `varbinary(max)` input it returns a `varchar(max)` result, i.e.: Base64 encoded data.
- When given `varchar(max)` input it returns a `varbinary(max)` result. If the input isn't valid Base64 encoded data it returns `NULL`.

e.g.:

```sql
create table dbo.Demo (
  ID int not null identity(1,1),
  ImageData varbinary(max)
);

insert dbo.Demo (ImageData) values (null);

declare @Base64Data varchar(max) = 'LzlqLzRB';
update dbo.Demo
set ImageData = cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@Base64Data"))', 'varbinary(max)') 
where ID = 1;

select * from dbo.Demo;
```

=====

Edit: if you have already stored your base64 data into `varbinary(max)` you will need to cast it to `varchar(max)` before supplying it to `xs:base64Binary()`, e.g.:

```sql
create table dbo.Demo (
  ID int not null identity(1,1),
  ImageData varbinary(max)
);

insert dbo.Demo (ImageData) values ( cast('LzlqLzRB' as varbinary(max)) );

select * from dbo.Demo; -- base64 characters as varbinary

update Dmo
set ImageData = cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("Base64Data"))', 'varbinary(max)') 
from dbo.Demo Dmo
outer apply ( select Base64Data = cast(ImageData as varchar(max)) ) Cst
where ID = 1;

select * from dbo.Demo; -- decoded data as varbinary
```

Comment: Hi! try the following update:

update table set D10Image = cast ('' as xml) .value ('xs: base64Binary (sql: column ("D10Image"))', 'varbinary (max)') where id = 1

but it doesn't change anything :( I still don't know why.

Comment: As per my introductory text `xs:base64Binary()` transforms `varbinary(max)` to base64 encoded data in `varchar(max)` or base64 encoded data in `varchar(max)` to `varbinary(max)`. If you've already crunched base64 encoded data into a `varbinary(max)` column you'll need to cast it to `varchar(max)` in an outer apply and supply that to `xs:base64Binary()`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning This comment actually saved the day for me. I was struggling to understand why the b64 that it spat out at me was different from what I originally put into the table, and now I know it's because I needed to cast as a varchar (nvarchar in my case). Now the images show up correctly.